# Monaca for Visual Studioでのクライアントへの保存

Tags: monaca, visual-studio

Monaca for Visual Studioでmonacaのプロジェクトをクライアントに保存しようとすると「インターフェースがサポートされていません」のエラーメッセージが出るのですがクライアントへの保存は出来ないのでしょうか？

Comment: 「クライアントへの保存」について詳しく教えていただけませんか？ 既にクラウド上にあるプロジェクトをローカルで開く場合は「Import from monaca.io」を選択することで、対象のプロジェクトをVisual Studioプロジェクトとして開くことができると思います。

Comment: 私も同じエラーが出ます。VS.net2015のソリューションごとセーブしようとするとこのエラーが出ます。
仕様ですか？

Comment: @MasaTanaka 憶測ですが、VisualStudioのプロジェクトをPC上に保存しようとするとエラーが出る、ということではないでしょうか。